# Collection Counter() function

Tags: python-3.x

**A problem with Counter() function in python.**

I meet this problem at the following code:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
counts1 = []
for row in data:
    counts[row[IMPORT_COMMUNICATION]]
```

why we have to assign Counter() to a variable at first? When I try to use the following code, I got this error. But counts is Counter() function right? That means in the first code block, I successfully assign value to Counter() function. While in the second block, I cannot assign value to Counter() function directly.

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
counts1 = []
for row in data:
    Counter([row[IMPORT_COMMUNICATION]]) += 1



File "<ipython-input-31-a9adc0c8c6ea>", line 6
    Counter([row[IMPORT_COMMUNICATION]]) += 1
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Does the type of Counter() change when it is assigned to count?

Comment: You are trying to assign a value to a function. you cannot do that . You have to assign it to a variable. Read more about [Counters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). I recommend you give `counts[whatever you want to add]`.

Comment: @Александр use English please

Comment: @Tibebes. M, yes, sorry.  
  
You should add the example `IMPORT_COMMUNICATION` and `data`. Otherwise, your example cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Even if this were valid, you would just create a new Counter on each iteration and then throw it away, because there is no name which refers to it. Compare `Counter()[row[IMPORT_COMMUNICATION]] += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a few questions that need to be answered.

You are trying to find the difference between these two lines of code.

```
counts = Counter()

counts1 = []
```

A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is a collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. So the variable `counts` will be a dictionary.

On the other hand, your variable `counts1` is a list. Also, later on you are trying to assign a value to a Counter class. You cannot assign values to a Class. You can assign to an instance of it and work with it as shown in below example.

The specific question you have is around

```
Counter([row[IMPORT_COMMUNICATION]]) += 1
```

In the above code, you are trying to assign a value (or increment) the Class Counter. You cannot do that. You have to instantiate it first and then use that variable. Please read more about [Class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) in the Python documentation.

The issue with your code has been addressed below:

Here is a simple implementation of [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as shown in the Python documentation.

```
>>> cnt = Counter()
>>> for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
...     cnt[word] += 1
>>> cnt
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
```

Let's look at your code and see what's happening. I have made some edits to include missing data items.

```
from collections import Counter

data = [[1,0],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,8],[7,9],[2,5]]    
IMPORT_COMMUNICATION = 0

counts = Counter()

#counts1 = [] - not required. commenting it out

for row in data:
    counts[row[IMPORT_COMMUNICATION]] +=1

print (counts)
```

In your code, you are trying to iterate through `data` and for every list item of `row`, you want to add +1 to each occurrence of `row[IMPORT_COMMUNICATION]` into `counts` Collection Counter object.

If you try to print counts, you will see the output as follows:

```
Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1, 8: 1, 7: 1})
```

Is this what you are trying to do? In this case, you will see there are two items in the list that has 1st position with value 2. Thats why the count for 2 is 2 and for all others its 1.

Comment: If the response addressed the problem, then you may want to read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Comment: This seems to fix the code but not actually address the question.

Comment: When I assign Counter() to counts, the operation ``counts[row[IMPORT_COMMUNICATION]]`` is valid. However, if I directly use Counter(), that is not valid. Why that happens?

Comment: Counter is a class. You are trying to assign to a Class. You cannot do that. You have to instantiate the class and then use it.

Comment: Please read more about [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) to understand the difference between the two things.

Comment: Note that a statement such as ``Counter(...) += 1`` does *not* assign to the class. It assigns to an *anonymous* target, since there is no way the *result* of ``Counter(...)`` could ever be referred to again. It can also not trigger side-effects, which only attribute and subscription assignment can do. As such, this *never* makes practical sense and is forbidden. Also note that the equivalent of ``counts[row[IMPORT_COMMUNICATION]]`` is actually ``Counter()[row[IMPORT_COMMUNICATION]]`` (mind the different parenthesis positions), which is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, this line makes no sense:

```
Counter([row[IMPORT_COMMUNICATION]]) += 1
```

You're trying to assign value to the function call which is not valid as error said.